# Showing continuity of $xy$ at all points

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

My friend asked me to show continuity of $f(x,y) = xy$ at all points in $\Bbb R^2$. I started

We need to show $|xy-ab| \lt \epsilon$ whenever $d((a,b), (x,y)) < \delta$.
So we have $|x-a| < \delta$ and $|y-b| < \delta$ then
$$|xy-ab | = |xy-ab-bx+bx-ay+ay-xy+xy-ab| \\
= |x(y-b) + y(x-a) -(x-a)(y-b)| \\
 < |x(y-b)| + |y(x-a)|+|(x-a)(y-b)|$$

Now we have $|x-a| < \delta$ or $a-\delta<x<a+\delta$ or $|x| < \max (|a+\delta|, |a-\delta|)$ and similarly $|y| < \max(|b-\delta|, |b+\delta|)$

So we obtain:

$$|xy-ab| < \delta (\max (|a+\delta|, |a-\delta))+\max(|b-\delta|, |b+\delta|)) \delta ^2 < \epsilon$$

Now how to conclude from here?? Do we take four cases?

Thanks a lot!

### Edit

As Holo said, i mistakenly didnt write modulus $|a-\delta|$, now I have edited.

Comment: You can use a little geometry if you want. Given a circle of radius $r$, you can inscribe a square of side length $r\sqrt{2}$. So, if $|x-a|<\delta \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $|y-b|<\delta \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, then $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add an subtract so much$$|xy-ab|=|xy-xb+xb-ab|\le|xy-xb|+|xb-ab|=|x||y-b|+|b||x-a|,$$ you can bound $|x|$ using delta and go on from there

---

In your case you have a little mistake: $a-\delta<x<a+\delta\implies |x| < \max (|a+\delta|, |a-\delta|)$, the $|\cdot|$ is important. From there you have $$|xy-ab| < \delta (\max (|a+\delta|, |a-\delta|)+\max(|b-\delta|, |b+\delta|)) \delta ^2 < \epsilon$$

Now you say that $\delta$ is **at most** $1$, so $\max (|a+\delta|, |a-\delta|),\max(|b-\delta|, |b+\delta|)<\max (|a+1|, |a-1|),\max(|b-1|, |b+1|)$, those $2$ are just regular old positive numbers, let's call them $A,B$ respectively.

Thus $$|xy-ab| < \delta (\max (|a+\delta|, |a-\delta|)+\max(|b-\delta|, |b+\delta|)) \delta ^2 < A\delta +B\delta ^2 =\epsilon$$

Now, because $Ax+Bx^2$ is bijective on $(0,\infty)$ it has inverse: $g(x)$(Just the positive side of the Quadratic Formula) so set $\delta=\min\{1,g(\epsilon)\}$

Comment: I moved your comma up to the displayed formula. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist not at all, thanks

Comment: @holo i understand i uselessly increased complexity, but my main quest is how to write about $|x|$ in statement, say it is quadratic, hopefully it is linear in your case so we are good, but what we can do in my case? :)

Comment: @jeea I edit it, please look now

Comment: @holo Oh dear I forgot to write modulus here, i had written it in my answer sheet ! I certainly think way better to go with your linear delta approach !!